# Origin not opening, and crashing after games close

Tags: technical-issues, origin

Recently I was playing Titan Fall 2 and saw it was late and closed it to go to bed. As I was shutting off my computer I saw an error message from Origin asking to restart or quit it. As it was late I quit it thinking nothing of it.

In the morning I went to re-open Origin and the same error message popped up. Hitting restart brought up the same error message. Thankfully I had the game's shortcut on my desktop and it opened just fine, with the Origin browser use button prompt popping up (I have not tried using it).

But when I close the game it still pops up the Origin error message. I have some games I don't have a shortcut for, and since I can't get into Origin, is there any way to play them? Also: is there a fix for this?

Comment: Can you provide us with the exact text of the error message? Is it just "Please restart or quit"?

Comment: @sirreldar It is just "Origin has encountered a serious problem and must close." along with info on what submitting your crash report does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to u/slayer_969 at https://www.reddit.com/r/origin/comments/as7v2r/origin_encountered_a_serious_problem_and_must/

> Turned out to be related to downloads, meaning origin was opening normally and crashed when i tried to download or update a game. The solution was one of the two steps i done: 1- Uninstall Origin then install it again. When installing uncheck update games automatically. Then the client should open and not crash. Then go to Application settings > click on Diagnostics > toggle-on Download in Safe mode. Restart the client and try downloading or updating a game. It should work. 2- Port Forwarding. I forwarded ports that origin uses. Go to www.portforward.com they have all the information you need to do it.
>
> I did both of these steps before retrying Origin so I don't know which fixed the issue for me. Good luck!

Comment: I have not yet tried porting forward, but I do not have a Safe Mode option in the diagnostic tab.